# How to add and id to an element in docusaurus?

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

They explain it on their docs, but it's only for headings [headings](https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/markdown-features/headings)

I've also read, that normally this is archived (in vanilla md) like this `[Some Text](/some/text/etc){#ID}`, but in Docusaurus this doesn't seem to work